# ossec 2.8.3 : getting autentication alerts from Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational

Tags: logging, rdp, windows-event-log, ossec

on **ossec 2.8.3** I am trying to get alerts only for rdp autentications from windows agents.

These events are shown in the clients event log
Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational
for example with *eventID 1149*

I have in my windows agents conf file

```
  <localfile>
    <location>Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational</location>
    <log_format>eventchannel</log_format>
  </localfile>
```

---

on the server in my local_rules.xml
I have

```
<group name="rdesktop">
<rule id="100888" level="1">
<match>Remote Desktop Services</match>
<description>Remote Desktop Connection Established</description>
</rule>
</group>
```

I get no messages from the remote client
(that sends alerts if I use     Security )

I see some traffic from client to server with tcpdump if I generate 1149 logon events
But no evidence even with
`<logall>yes</logall>`  in ossec server.

Anyone can share some insight?

Many thanks
g.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am misunderstanding. Need to add an option section in your local rules?

`<options>alert_by_email</options>`

Comment: I don't need alerts to be sent by email, my problem is it looks like alerts for rdp logins with this method are never raised. If I understood correctly if I set logall I shoud see the alert in ossec alerts.log. But I see no entry. I only see some packets with tcpdump from the client when I generate a 1149 event id from a rdp login.

Comment: Sorry! Needed to have a coffee to wake up. Are other alerts been logged for that client though? 

Might be worthwhile jumping on IRC irc.freenode.net on channel #ossec and ask there.

Comment: if I change the log to    <localfile>
    <location>Security</location>
    <log_format>eventlog</log_format>
  </localfile>  I get alerts logged , the problem is I have some servers that generate too much of those , thanks for the hint on irc channel, I'll try that as soon as I have some time to go there